# How to select multiple items from a listbox asp.net without pressing the CTRL key using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to select multiple items from a listbox without pressing the CTRL key using javascript?

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="Satellites"  runat="server" AppendDataBoundItem="true" AutoPostBack="true"  onchange='GetValueSatellite();' Width="400px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: If you want custom behavior then you'll probably have to build a custom tool.  I had a boss once who wanted a multi-select list box with little check boxes on each line.  I had to create a custom tool for this but it worked great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('option').mousedown(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
  return false;
 });
```

Comment: Doesn't get any simpler than this. Works great!